# How to transform XML attributes to an HTML table

Tags: html, xslt

Here is an excerpt from an xsl document (inside a template technically):

```
<table>
  <tr>
  <th>INSTANCE</th>
  <th>SWVER</th>
  <th>SYSTEMID</th>
  <th>SYSTIME</th>
  <th>SYSMEM</th>
  <th>CUTMEM</th>
  <th>FILEMEM</th>
  <th>CALCONFIG</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><xsl:value-of select='@INSTANCE'/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select='@SWVER'/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select='@SYSTEMID'/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select='@SYSTIME'/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select='@SYSMEM'/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select='@CUTMEM'/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select='@FILEMEM'/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="@CALCONFIG"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is there some way that I can avoid the redundancy of writing out the attributes both as table headers and as the attribute selection? I cannot use external sources.

I was thinking I could define some xsl variable that contains a basic structure, as follows and generate the table from there.

```
<list>
  <item>INSTANCE</item>
  ...
  <item>CALCONFIG</item>
</list>
```

The XML data is just a bunch of tags, of the same value that contain at least the above listed attributes. Each tag looks something like this:

```
<THING INSTANCE="boop" SWVER="foo" SYSTEMID="123" 
...
CALCONFIG="cal.cfg" SOMETHINGELSE="bar"
/>
```

Comment: You need to show the input XML and the complete stylesheet.

Comment: Done. Got any ideas?

Comment: IMHO, the  alternative will end up more verbose and less readable than what you have - exp. if you're using XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @michael.hor257k If there is some sort of alternative I'd still be quite interested. Thanks!

Comment: Which version of XSLT does your processor support?

Comment: @michael.hor257k: I'm using a web browser, usually Firefox (sometimes older versions).  A quick Google search tells me that means XSLT 2.0 is not yet supported... so XSLT 1.0? I just started working on web related technologies, so I'm not super sure about this information.

Comment: Browsers support XSLT 1.0 only, and that's not expected to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To illustrate the point I made in a comment to your question, consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <item color="red" name="alpha" size="small" garbage="123" id="1"/>
    <item color="green" name="bravo" size="medium" garbage="456" id="2"/>
    <item color="blue" name="charlie" size="large" garbage="789" id="3"/>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:my="http://www.example.com/my"
exclude-result-prefixes="my">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<my:columns>
    <col>id</col>
    <col>name</col>
    <col>size</col>
    <col>color</col>
</my:columns>
<xsl:variable name="columns" select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/my:columns" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="$columns/col">
                <th>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </th>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="item">
            <xsl:variable name="attributes" select="@*" />
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="$columns/col">
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$attributes[name()=current()]" />
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result (rendered)**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Michael, this is what I was looking for, even though it's less readable, it's probably going to save me some time.

Comment: One question, what does this line do?  `exclude-result-prefixes="my"`
I'm also curious as to why the namespace makes this work.  Do you have anything you could point me to, or just explain here?

Comment: It prevents the namespace declaration `xmlns:my="http://www.example.com/my"`from appearing in the output. Any modern browser would ignore it anyway, so it's just a matter of good practice. -- The namespace is required, because without it `columns` would be interpreted as a [literal result element](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#literal-result-element) and cause an error, since a literal result element cannot be outside of a template.

Comment: Thanks, another question though! How does this line work: 
`<xsl:value-of select="$attributes[name()=current()]"`
I understand that `attributes` holds all the attributes for the `item` currently being evaluated and that we're basically looking up the attribute that matches the current column... but unless I'm missing something `name()` evaluates to `col` and `current()` evaluates to one of the column names.  How would this line change if the column name were an attribute instead? e.g. `<col name="id"/>` instead of `<col>id</col>`  Thanks!

Comment: The instruction selects from `$attributes` the attribute whose name is equal to the string-value of the current node. The current node is the current instance of `col` from `$columns`. If column name were an attribute, you'd have to say `<xsl:value-of select="$attributes[name()=current()/@name()]`. See: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates and :https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#misc-func

Answer (score -1):

Bryant, you need to work with two files (XML and XSL):

First, you need to specify a template (example.xsl):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My Collection</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>instance</th>
      <th>swver</th>
      <th>systemid</th>
      <th>systime</th>
      <th>sysmem</th>
      <th>cutmem</th>
      <th>filemem</th>
      <th>calconfig</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="instance"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="swver"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="systemid"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="systime"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="sysmem"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="cutmem"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="filemem"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="calconfig"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And then you need to define your XML file (example.xml), based on the template (example.xsl):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="example.xsl"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <instance>instance1</instance>
    <swver>swver1</swver>
    <systemid>systemid1</systemid>
    <sysmem>sysmem1</sysmem>
    <systime>systime1</systime>
    <cutmem>cutmem1</cutmem>
    <filemem>filemem1</filemem>
    <calconfig>calconfig1</calconfig>

  </cd>
  <cd>
    <instance>instance2</instance>
    <swver>swver2</swver>
    <systemid>systemid2</systemid>
    <sysmem>sysmem2</sysmem>
    <systime>systime2</systime>
    <cutmem>cutmem2</cutmem>
    <filemem>filemem2</filemem>
    <calconfig>calconfig2</calconfig>

  </cd>
.
.
</catalog>
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Reference:**
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp

Hope this helps!

Comment: You didn't answer the question, just gave back what the OP has already said he's done.  Please reread the question carefully.